# weird gcc behavior with unsigned ints

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint16_t ii; 
    std::cin >> ii;                                                    
    printf("%d\n", ii);
}
```

When I give input `5` the output is also `5`. But when I change the type of `ii` to `uint8_t`, I do not get `5` but `53` which seems to be the ASCII value of `5`. Is this expected?

Comment: But, I have used printf not cout right. Isn't the problem with cin?

Comment: printing is also problematic, why do you cast to `uint8_t`?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath right..the way I print is also wrong. But somehow it prints right value.. Not sure why though

Comment: as it is usually with C & C++, this is the result of luck and/or implementation defined (or not even defined) behaviour. detective columbo is just preparing the answer for you. in this case, the sign bit was 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`uint8_t` is allowed (but not required) to be a typedef for `char` (if it happens to be unsigned) or `unsigned char`. And input of those is done as characters not numbers. So this is valid but not required behaviour.

Comment: I know that's what you meant, but to be clear: some implementations make `char` signed, others make it unsigned. On implementations where it is signed, `uint8_t` is not allowed to be a typedef for `char`. On implementations where it is unsigned, it is allowed.

Comment: `uint16_t` might also be `unsigned char` of course - although you're less likely to come across that in practice.

Comment: @hvd Thanks. Clarified.

Comment: @AlanStokes On a system where `uint16_t` is `unsigned char`, `uint8_t` would not exist and the OP's code would not compile :)